# Fire server side button click and client side click asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Is it possible to fire a server side button click and a javascript button click at the same time?

Comment: You'll fire the javascript one first, and then the server one.  Explain what you're trying to actually do and give us some code and we can do something for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Not in the same time, If you add `onclientclick` the browser will fire the javascript and if it returns true it will fire the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can wire your button to do both, but the client-side click will happen first and the server-side click will happen, as long as the client-side click logic does not prevent it from happening, like this:

```
$("#YourButtonID").click(function () {
    // Do something here

    // Prevent the server-side click event from firing
    return false;
});
```

Note: Leaving out the `return false;` part will allow the server-side click to happen.

Comment: Ok here is the wrinkle, the javascript code changes the window location so I can't return true first otherwise it wont redirect, if I do it after it is too late.